# Getting user statuses/posts using API

Tags: facebook, search, post, facebook-graph-api, status

I want to collect some posts/statuses using https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=sampleword, but it didn't return any results.
I use this word in my status: http://www.facebook.com/100002364215777/posts/189715107783962 , so it should be found.

What I did wrong/how to do it in another way?

Answer (score 0):

For a start you will need to regeister as a facebook developer and get an access token.

Please read the [Graph API doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) It will tell you more about Authorization and how to do Searches.

Comment: Yes, I have a facebook developer account and I test this request in Graph API Explorer when I get access token (I suppose). I also add "&type=post" to the request, but with no result.
So what else is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer few days ago - it's a bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/251747031550291?browse=search_4ede11dc12bef5f22614385